# Create Synonyms from Tibco, businessworks and tibco-business-works tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I was reviewing some edit suggestions in the review queue when the following question appeared:

[TIBCO BW functions group not appearing in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055387/tibco-bw-functions-group-not-appearing-in-xpath)

There was a proposed edit on this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11276779

to add the [tibco-business-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tibco-business-works) and [tibco-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tibco-designer) tags. While the [tibco-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tibco-designer) seemed like it may be legitimate, the [tibco-business-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tibco-business-works) seemed redundant since the question was already tagged with both [tibco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tibco) and [businessworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/businessworks). Should any of these tags be merged, burninated or marked as synonyms of one another?

Comment: It has currently only been edited onto [3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tibco-business-works), all edits were done by [Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1702943/rao).  I had the same question when reviewing that edit and was going to ask how to flag `tibco-business-works`.  It was created today and has none of the content a good tag should have.